# Desktop guide for 11.04 provides incorrect information

Tags: 11.04, unity, helpfile

In Ubuntu Natty, the Ubuntu desktop guide (f1 option from desktop). When you highlight 4 out of the 5 top links it shows a screenshot of gnome-shell and not of unity this could be confusing for new users.

I was going to raise a bug for this but don't know what package it belongs to.

the links affected are: 
start applications 
windows and workspaces 
logout, power off and switch users
overview of the desktop.

Comment: Errors in the guides and manuals are bugs too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug and is being worked on: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/753072

GNOME completely rewrote the user help but this new version was only officially released about 10 days ago. We are off to a late start but I believe we'll have the essential help converted to describe the Ubuntu interface by Ubuntu 11.04's release.

If you'd like to help, consider joining the [Ubuntu Documentation Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-doc-contributors).